# Command line parser of 4-digit number as argument with many combinations (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-arguments, argparse

I want to have the user to provide a configuration setting by giving a 4-digit number as an argument. Each digit would correspond to an `True` or `False` state for a specific setting `A`, `B`, `C`, or `D`.

```
   A  B  C  D
   0  1  0  0  # would indicate that the user wants B setting only
   1  1  0  1  # would indicate that the user wants the A, B and D settings
```

There are 16 such setting combinations.

Then, I will take that argument and handle it on a letter-by-letter basis.

I thought of something like this where I state all allowable values:

```
import argparse

argparser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description= "blah blah"
)

argparser.add_argument(
    "-cs", "configuration_setting",
    choices=["1111", "1110", ..., "0001", "0000"]  # all 16 combinations
    dest="config_setting"
)
```

Is there any more efficient (or more 'pythonic') approach of handling all 16 possible `choices`? Should I not use `choices` but simply get a 3-letter input and then handle it? Note that I am interested on how to check that the user provided an allowable input.

Comment: Why don't you let the user specify each option individually? To enable `A` type `-A` etc. Like that each config option could have its own description and since you split the binary string manually anyway it doesn't add too much overhead.

Comment: `choices` is efficient, since all it does is a `in choices` test.  But have you looked at the help display?  Alternatives are a custom `type` function, or post parsing testing.  All are "pythonic".

Answer (score 1):

If it was hard to get the command line parser to validate the string, I'd accept any string and validate it with my own code.

A sixteen-element hard-coded list isn't excessive, but you could generate your list like this

```
['{:04b}'.format(i) for i in range(16) ]
```

More Pythonic? Not sure in this case, but definitely so if it were

```
['{:07b}'.format(i) for i in range(128) ]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you define a `type` function like:

```
def forbool(astr):
    choices = [''.join(x) for x in product(['0','1'],repeat=4)]
    if astr in choices:
        return astr
    else:
        raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError('your message')
```

It needs to return some value if the `astr` is valid, and raise an error if not.  Here I return the string itself, but it could transformed into a number or list or what ever you like.

`foobool` could have issued a `TypeError` or `ValueError`, but `ArgumentTypeError` lets you set the error message.

It is used as

```
parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--cs', type=forbool, help='value like 0101')

parser.parse_args(['--cs','0100'])
Out[26]: Namespace(cs='0100')

In [27]: parser.parse_args(['--cs','0103'])
usage: ipython3 [-h] [--cs CS]
ipython3: error: argument --cs: your message

In [28]: parser.parse_args(['--cs','01001'])
usage: ipython3 [-h] [--cs CS]
ipython3: error: argument --cs: your message
```

With `choices` the error looks like

```
parser.add_argument('-f', choices=choices, help='value like 0101')
In [32]: parser.parse_args(['-f','01001'])
usage: ipython3 [-h] [--cs CS]
                [-f {0000,0001,0010,0011,0100,0101,0110,0111,1000,1001,1010,1011,1100,1101,1110,1111}]
ipython3: error: argument -f: invalid choice: '01001' (choose from '0000', '0001', '0010', '0011', '0100', '0101', '0110', '0111', '1000', '1001', '1010', '1011', '1100', '1101', '1110', '1111')
```

Functionally the use of `choices` is efficient (but we don't need to worry about efficiency with `argparse`), but the usage/help/error gets quite messy  when the list is long.  A `metavar` gives you control over the usage and help, but the error message is still long.

There's nothing wrong with doing the testing afterwards as with:

```
 if args.cs is not None:
    try: 
        cs = forbool(args.cs)
    except argparse.ArgumentTypeError():
        parser.error('your message')
```

Calling `parser.error...` issues the `usage` along with the error message.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a simple for loop which would provide you with a lot more flexibility in the long term. The following for-loop outputs a multidimensional list of ones and zeroes:

```
    # Part 1, Creating the multidimensional lists:

data = {
        'A':[True,False],
        'B':[True,False],
        'C':[True,True],
        'D':[False,True]
        }

config = {  'A':[],
            'B':[],
            'C':[],
            'D':[]}

# Part 2, Building the for-loop which appends the values to the list

abcd = ["A","B","C","D"]

for user in range(len(data["A"])): #range(len(data[A])) gives the number of users in the database
    for letter in abcd:
        if data[letter][user] == True:
            config[letter].append(0)
        else:
            config[letter].append(1)

print (config)
```